# onsenui: Slidemenu width is not working right when screen width change (portrait to landscape)

Tags: html

When I view app in portrait mode and slide left to right, the above page cover around 10% on the right edge of below page. And i rotate screen to landscape mode, the above page cover 50% of the below page. How can i make it consistent between portrait and landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use max-slide-distance.

```
<ons-sliding-menu max-slide-distance="50%">
```

Comment: Thanks. But it will cover the contain in below page on small screen device, if the contain in below page width is larger than 50% of the page.